# Java Calendar always shows the same time

Tags: java, calendar

Below is my code.

```
public class TestCalendar {

public static void main(String[] args){
    int unique_id = Integer.parseInt("" + Calendar.HOUR + Calendar.MINUTE
            + Calendar.SECOND);

    System.out.println(unique_id);
}
}
```

Calendar.HOUR is supposed to give me

> public static final int HOUR Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the morning or 
>    afternoon. HOUR is used for the 12-hour clock (0 - 11). Noon and midnight are represented by 0, not 
>    by 12. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR is 10.

It doesnt matter how many times I run this code, it always gives me the same unique_id. (101213) and my local time on my machine is 1:30pm. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? If you're just trying to get a unique value, going down to the second is unlikely to achieve it anyway - but you can do that without any string handling or calendar access.

Comment: To get a unique id based on time, you better use Calendar.getTimeInMillis()

Comment: @Jayaraj using milliseconds results in higher _precision_ but still falls short of being "unique" in many cases

Comment: What you seem to be trying to obtain will give you the same “unique” ID at times 01:01:23, 01:12:03, 11:02:03, 13:01:23, 13:12:03 and 23:02:03, namely 1123. Wonder how unique you want it? In any case, in 2018 use `LocalTime` from [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) for getting the time of day as numbers. `Calendar` is long outdated and `java.time` so much nicer to work with. Maybe `LocalTime.toSecondOfDay​()` can give you a suitable ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is just concatenating constants, that the Calendar defines to identify some of it's fields. To get values of these fields, call `Calendar.get()` and pass the constant identifier as an argument:

```
public class TestCalendar {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int unique_id = Integer.parseInt("" + c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
            + c.get(Calendar.SECOND));

    System.out.println(unique_id);
}
}
```

The above would work, but the result will be far from unique ID.
To get an ID uniquely identifying a point in time (with the precision of milliseconds), consider [`Calendar.getTimeInMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis()).

Comment: `Calendar` here is a class, not a variable name of a reference to an instance, so calling the non-static `get(int field)` method won't compile.

Comment: @WilliamPrice So shall I do a getInstance of Calendar, and then do a getmethod?

Comment: @davida Yeah, I don't really want it to be 'unique' unique. I just want to register the time when user registered something. It doesnt really have to be super precise. Thanks alot.

Comment: @Kraken Yes, you need an instance of `Calendar`.  I see _david a._ has updated his answer here with an example.

Answer (score 3):

`Calendar.HOUR`, `Calendar.MINUTE` and `Calendar.SECOND` are `public static int` field of the `Calendar` class. Their value is

- CALENDAR.HOUR: 10
- CALENDAR.MINUTE: 12 and
- CALENDAR.SECOND: 13.

Your `String` concatenation is just appending this values. To read from a `Calendar` you could so something similar to

```
calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Calendar.HOUR` (or `MINUTE`, `SECOND`) is just an indicator that indicates which field we want to extract from the `Calendar` instance, not the value, i.e. we want to 'extract HOUR from the calendar object' like below:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // in 24-hours,
                                        // or c.get(Calendar.HOUR) in 12-hours.
int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int second = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

int weekday = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int weekOfYear = c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is requirement but if you want system time then may be you can use this "System.currentTimeMillis()"

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still having some problems with this, like I did, especially when you want to print multiple times you may need to to use new like follows:

```
System.out.println(""+new GregorianCalendar().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+new GregorianCalendar().get(Calendar.MINUTE)+":"+new GregorianCalendar().get(Calendar.SECOND)+":"+new GregorianCalendar().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
```

Comment: This may give you for example `13:6:5:96`. Was this what you wanted? Also with multiple calls to `new` you risk that the time changes between them so the output is inconsistent.

Comment: the only time change possible would be between the time the hour prints and the milliseconds do. which, lets be honest, really isnt that bad.